# symfony2 php access object of another entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know its very lame question to ask. I have One Entity ContentSelector and another is Content in Content Selector I have a property Content where I have Id. I am trying to access the Content propety but always getting error. This is what I am trying to do.

```
$cs = $pages->getContentSelector();
```

it returns:

```
[

{
    "id": ​22,
    "title": "my Title",
    "content": "11021,10930,10874,10766,10954,10705,10948,10934,11048,11049,10831"
}

]
```

now I want to get the content property like `$cs->content` getting error like:

```
"Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection::$content"
```

tried with getContent(); getting error that the method doesnt exist. but in ContentSelector the method actually exists.

how can I easily get the content ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getContentSelector() method return an [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) so you need to access to an element of the collection before call a method of the contained object. As example, you can access to the first element as follow:

```
$collection = $pages->getContentSelector();
$cs = $collection->first();
```

Then you can try access to the objet element (from the dump seems a json object?)

Hope this help

Comment: thanks you very much $cs->getContent(); i can access the method now.

Comment: Hi @SamiaRuponti you are welcome! You can access to the first object of the collection (as the example) or filter by a condition for select a right one, let me know if you need some help!

Comment: no im getting the contents now but prob is getting as string, but i will figure that to convert array so that i can find contents by findBy();